# How to correctly invalidate layout for supplementary views in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am having a dataset displayed in a `UICollectionView`. The dataset is split into sections and each section has a header. Further, each cell has a detail view underneath it that is expanded when the cell is clicked.

For reference:

[image]

For simplicity, I have implemented the details cells as standard cells that are hidden (height: 0) by default and when the non-detail cell is clicked, the height is set to non-zero value. The cells are updates using `invalidateItems(at indexPaths: [IndexPath])` instead of reloading cells in `performBatchUpdates(_ updates: (() -> Void)?, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)` as the animations seems glitchy otherwise.

Now to the problem, the `invalidateItems` function obviously updates only cells, not supplementary views like the section header and therefore calling only this function will result in overflowing the section header:

[image]

After some time Googling, I found out that in order to update also the supplementary views, one has to call `invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPaths: [IndexPath])`. This might recalculate the section header's bounds correctly, however results in the content not appearing:

[image]

This is most likely caused due to the fact that the `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView` does not seem to be called.

I would be extremely grateful if somebody could tell me how to correctly invalidate supplementary views to the issues above do not happen.

**Code**:

```
   override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return dataManager.getSectionCount()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let count = dataManager.getSectionItemCount(section: section)
        reminder = count % itemsPerWidth
        return count * 2
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if isDetailCell(indexPath: indexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Reusable.CELL_SERVICE, for: indexPath) as! ServiceCollectionViewCell
            cell.lblName.text = "Americano detail"

            cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexString: "#999999").cgColor
            return cell

        } else {
            let item = indexPath.item > itemsPerWidth ? indexPath.item - (((indexPath.item / itemsPerWidth) / 2) * itemsPerWidth) : indexPath.item
            let product = dataManager.getItem(index: item, section: indexPath.section)

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Reusable.CELL_SERVICE, for: indexPath) as! ServiceCollectionViewCell
            cell.lblName.text = product.name

            cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexString: "#999999").cgColor

            return cell
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: Reusable.CELL_SERVICE_HEADER_ROOT, for: indexPath) as! ServiceCollectionViewHeaderRoot
                header.lblCategoryName.text = "Section Header"
                header.imgCategoryBackground.af_imageDownloader = imageDownloader
                header.imgCategoryBackground.af_setImage(withURLRequest: ImageHelper.getURL(file: category.backgroundFile!))
                return header
            } else {
                let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: Reusable.CELL_SERVICE_HEADER, for: indexPath) as! ServiceCollectionViewHeader
                header.lblCategoryName.text = "Section Header"
                return header
            }
        default:
            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
        }
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.frame.size.width / CGFloat(itemsPerWidth)

        if isDetailCell(indexPath: indexPath) {
            if expandedCell == indexPath {
                return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: width)
            } else {
                return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 0)
            }
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        if section == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height / 3)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: heightHeader)
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if isDetailCell(indexPath: indexPath) {
            return
        }

        var offset = itemsPerWidth
        if isLastRow(indexPath: indexPath) {
            offset = reminder
        }

        let detailPath = IndexPath(item: indexPath.item + offset, section: indexPath.section)
        let context = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext()

        let maxItem = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1
        var minItem = detailPath.item
        if let expandedCell = expandedCell {
            minItem = min(minItem, expandedCell.item)
        }

        // TODO: optimize this
        var cellIndexPaths = (0 ... maxItem).map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: 0) }

        var supplementaryIndexPaths = (0..<collectionView.numberOfSections).map { IndexPath(item: 0, section: $0)}

        for i in indexPath.section..<collectionView.numberOfSections {
            cellIndexPaths.append(contentsOf: (0 ... collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: i) - 1).map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: i) })
            //supplementaryIndexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: 0, section: i))
        }

        context.invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: supplementaryIndexPaths)
        context.invalidateItems(at: cellIndexPaths)

        if detailPath == expandedCell {
            expandedCell = nil
        } else {
            expandedCell = detailPath
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: context)
            collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**:
Minimalistic project demonstrating this issue: https://github.com/vongrad/so-expandable-collectionview

Comment: brief directly where did you stuck. and what u tried

Comment: why not use collectionView.reloadSections(:)?

Comment: I started with reloading individual items as well as reloading entire sections (as suggested by @sj-r), however this resulted in animations that were far off from being smooth. Therefore I moved to invalidation context and pretty much tried the things mentioned in my question.

Comment: Try to call [supplementaryView setNeedsDisplay].

Comment: I already tried that but it did not work

Comment: Dont use height:0 in `sizeforItemAt` rather use `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude `. Apple Docs says not use return 0 height or width from sizeForItem. I forgot what it exaclty does when you set it to 0 but this might be the issue. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview?language=objc

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 9):

You should use an Invalidation Context. It's a bit complex, but here's a rundown:

First, you need to create a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext` since the default one used by most collection views will just refresh everything. There may be situations where you DO want to refresh everything though; in my instance, if the width of the collection view changes it has to layout all the cells again, so my solution looks like this:

```
class CustomInvalidationContext: UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
    var justHeaders: Bool = false
    override var invalidateEverything: Bool { return !justHeaders }
    override var invalidateDataSourceCounts: Bool { return false }
}
```

Now you need to tell the layout to use this context instead of the default:

```
override class var invalidationContextClass: AnyClass {
    return CustomInvalidationContext.self
}
```

This won't trigger if we don't tell the layout it needs to update upon scrolling, so:

```
override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

I'm passing `true` here because there will always be something to update when the user scrolls the collection view, even if it's only the header frames. We'll determine exactly what gets changed when in the next section.

Now that it is always updating when the bounds change, we need to provide it with information about which parts should be invalidated and which should not. To make this easier, I have a function called `getVisibleSections(in: CGRect)` that returns an optional array of integers representing which sections overlap the given bounds rectangle. I won't detail this here as yours will be different. I'm also caching the content size of the collection view as `_contentSize` since this only changes when a full layout occurs.

With a small number of sections you could probably just invalidate all of them. Be that as it may, we now need to tell the layout how to set up its invalidation context when the bounds changes.

***Note:** make sure you're calling `super` to get the context rather than just creating one yourself; this is the proper way to do things.*

```
override func invalidationContext(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
    let context = super.invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: newBounds) as! CustomInvalidationContext
    
    // If we can't determine visible sections or the width has changed,
    // we need to do a full layout - just return the default.
    guard newBounds.width == _contentSize.width,
        let visibleSections = getVisibleSections(in: newBounds)
    else { return context }
    
    // Determine which headers need a frame change.
    context.justHeaders = true
    let sectionIndices = visibleSections.map { IndexPath(item: 0, section: $0) }
    context.invalidateSupplementaryElements(ofKind: "Header", at: sectionIndices)
    return context
}
```

Note that I'm assuming your supplementary view kind is "Header"; change that if you need to. Now, provided that you've properly implemented `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView` to return a suitable frame, your headers (and only your headers) should update as you scroll vertically.

Keep in mind that `prepare()` will NOT be called unless you do a full invalidation, so if you need to do any recalculations, override `invalidateLayout(with:)` as well, calling super at some point. Personally I do the calculations for shifting the header frames in `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView` as it's simpler and just as performant.

Oh, and one last small tip: on the layout attributes for your headers, don't forget to set `zIndex` to a higher value than the one in your cells so that they definitely appear in front. The default is 0, I use 1 for my headers.

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest is to create a separate subclass of a  UICollectionFlowView

and set it up respectivel look at this example:

```
import UIKit

class StickyHeadersCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    // MARK: - Collection View Flow Layout Methods

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }

        // Helpers
        let sectionsToAdd = NSMutableIndexSet()
        var newLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for layoutAttributesSet in layoutAttributes {
            if layoutAttributesSet.representedElementCategory == .cell {
                // Add Layout Attributes
                newLayoutAttributes.append(layoutAttributesSet)

                // Update Sections to Add
                sectionsToAdd.add(layoutAttributesSet.indexPath.section)

            } else if layoutAttributesSet.representedElementCategory == .supplementaryView {
                // Update Sections to Add
                sectionsToAdd.add(layoutAttributesSet.indexPath.section)
            }
        }

        for section in sectionsToAdd {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)

            if let sectionAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath) {
                newLayoutAttributes.append(sectionAttributes)
            }
        }

        return newLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: elementKind, at: indexPath) else { return nil }
        guard let boundaries = boundaries(forSection: indexPath.section) else { return layoutAttributes }
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return layoutAttributes }

        // Helpers
        let contentOffsetY = collectionView.contentOffset.y
        var frameForSupplementaryView = layoutAttributes.frame

        let minimum = boundaries.minimum - frameForSupplementaryView.height
        let maximum = boundaries.maximum - frameForSupplementaryView.height

        if contentOffsetY < minimum {
            frameForSupplementaryView.origin.y = minimum
        } else if contentOffsetY > maximum {
            frameForSupplementaryView.origin.y = maximum
        } else {
            frameForSupplementaryView.origin.y = contentOffsetY
        }

        layoutAttributes.frame = frameForSupplementaryView

        return layoutAttributes
    }

    // MARK: - Helper Methods

    func boundaries(forSection section: Int) -> (minimum: CGFloat, maximum: CGFloat)? {
        // Helpers
        var result = (minimum: CGFloat(0.0), maximum: CGFloat(0.0))

        // Exit Early
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return result }

        // Fetch Number of Items for Section
        let numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)

        // Exit Early
        guard numberOfItems > 0 else { return result }

        if let firstItem = layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)),
           let lastItem = layoutAttributesForItem(at: IndexPath(item: (numberOfItems - 1), section: section)) {
            result.minimum = firstItem.frame.minY
            result.maximum = lastItem.frame.maxY

            // Take Header Size Into Account
            result.minimum -= headerReferenceSize.height
            result.maximum -= headerReferenceSize.height

            // Take Section Inset Into Account
            result.minimum -= sectionInset.top
            result.maximum += (sectionInset.top + sectionInset.bottom)
        }

        return result
    }

}
```

then add your collection view to your view controller and this way you will implement the invalidation methods which currently are not getting triggered.

source [here](https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-sticky-section-headers-to-a-collection-view)

Comment: I tried the layoutIfNeeded already in the past and it did not work. Reloading the entire collectionView is not a solution either as it’s inefficient and results in screen blinking :/

Comment: try the whole solution as from what I read in apple's docs once you invalidate the supplement views they will not get updated

Comment: Also, invalidateSupplementaryViews is registered properly

Comment: try a print statement in func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView  to see if it gets called after all

Comment: if it won't give you any hints then you can share the code on gitHub or elsewhere I can try to contribute if you want

Comment: I am aware that the viewForSupplementaryElement is not getting called as I already wrote in my question description  so that’s one of the issues. Unfortunately, it is not an option to reload entire collectionView on every cell collapse/expand. Once I get home, I can set up a sample GitHub project with this issue.

Comment: check my latest edit just found that an issue is with old obj-c referencing and the delegate methods are not called without the @objc keyword before them

Comment: I tried adding the @objc keyword, however that did not have any effect.... I have also verified that the suplementaryIndexPaths are properly set, so the issue is not there.

Comment: The only solution that I have found so far (and I am not very proud of) is resetting the collectionViewLayout that forces recalculation of frames - collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true). The main issue with this approach is that everything gets recalculated, however there is no blinking and animations are smooth. I would be still more than happy to accept any more efficient solution.

Comment: Can you setup a project on github so that I can see the issue

Comment: Hey, I am sorry for the delay. I created a minimalistic project on GitHub that demonstrates this problem - see my edit.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have done a small adjustment in your code. Seems to get you closer to the solution. What I noticed that the section header not only disappears from the screen but gets completely removed from the view hierarchy check the pull request on github

Comment: Yes that's right. I have just looked at your commit and the code change you made looks incorrect: (minSection + 1..<collectionView.numberOfSections).map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: minSection)}. Not the invalidationContext does not select the supplementary view correctly. (Each section has one header)

Comment: I know. but after the change I have made if you build you will have the section sliding downwards only half way thru there seems to be a problem with constraints or recalculation of the section headers bounds

Comment: I just noticed that the section header supposed to move down but it does not that is the cause of whole issue

Comment: The section header does not disappear because it is not invalidated (recalculated) because the array of supplementary indexPaths is incorrect and will never point to it - (minSection + 1..<collectionView.numberOfSections).map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: minSection)}

Comment: I got it now. Sorry my bad. I don't get this why is it getting thrown away from the view hierarchy I reverted back to your code and that is something I don't understand. If I use collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() then it does recalculate everything but the animation is looking dodgy

Comment: have a look at this link it has a tutorial about sticky section headers and invalidation. https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-sticky-section-headers-to-a-collection-view

Answer (score 1):

Do reloadLoad cells in `performBatchUpdates(_:)` make it seems glitchy.

Just pass nil like below to update your cell's height.

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
```

**EDIT:**

I have recently found that `performBatchUpdates(_:)` only shift the header along with cell new height returned from the `sizeForItemAt` function. If using collection view cell sizing, your supplementary view may overlaps the cells. Then `collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout` will fix without showing the animation.

If you want to go with sizing animation after calling `performBatchUpdates(_:)`, try to calculate (then cache) and return cell's size in `sizeForItemAt`. It works for me.